# JS Check Jquery inArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like to use a onchange state on a select element to check if the value of the select is in an array.

I tried this :

```
function statutEmployeur(){
   statliste = [];
   statliste.push(1);
   statliste.push(2);
   statliste.push(5);
   statid = jQuery("#statut").val();
   if(jQuery.inArray(statid,statliste)>-1){
      alert('inside array');
   }else {
      alert('outside array');
   }
}
```

Each value that I tried are outside of the array.
Anybody can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: hey there i'd love to help you, mind throwing your current code (html,js) up into jsbin? makes it easier to give you specific advice.

Comment: Is this possibly a type issue? `"1"` is not considered to be in an array of `[1, 2, 5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as pointed out by [Stryner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3900153/stryner) in the comments, try running your `.val()` through `parseInt()` to ensure you nave a numerical value (and not a string)

```
   statid = jQuery("#statut").val();
```

to:

```
   statid = parseInt(jQuery("#statut").val(), 10);
```

working fiddle: http://jsbin.com/maqesupuka/edit?html,js,console,output

the problem is you're searching in the array for a type of string (default type of inputs), but your array only contains numbers. You could either make your array into numbers, or do a type conversion like above to ensure you're working with the same type.